# how can i display errors message on blade template of laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created laravel 5.2 project. I have been created login page but I am stuck on display validation errors message on blade template. I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Please help me for this issue. Thanks!

View

```
 <div>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
    @if($errors->has('email')) <p>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p> @endif
 </div>
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view('user.login');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handlelogin(Request $request)
    {
        $messages = array(
            'email.required'=>'You cant leave Email field empty',
            'password.required'=>'You cant leave name field empty'
        );

        $rules = array(
            'email' => 'required|email|max:20',
            'password' => 'required'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());

        }else{
        
            $data = $request->only('email','password');


            if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
                return redirect()->intended('/');
            }

        return back()->withInput();
        }
    }

 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to check for errors, just do as following

```blade
{!! $errors->first('email', '<div class="error-block">:message</div>') !!}
```

please note that "error-block" is a custom css class and you can customize html template according to your choice.

[Retrieving An Error Message With A Format](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#working-with-error-messages)

---

Comment: add `{{dd($errors->all())}}` to view. then check your error message is in there

Comment: Ok, I found this message.  object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#185 (1) {
  ["bags":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Comment: First load the page in browser, then add `{{dd($errors->all())}}`. Then fill the form with invalid data and submit. What's the output?

Comment: After submit the form. Only display [ ] .

Comment: remove the `dd` and try with `$this->validate($request, $rules);` on the controller instead of `Validator::make()`

Answer (score 0):

I have different approach.

Below input field I include additional view:

```
@include('input-errors', ['inputName' => 'inputName']) #For your case it would be 'email'
```

input-errors.blade.php

```
@foreach ($errors->get($inputName) as $message)
    <span class="input-error">{{ $message }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Styles.css

```
.input-error {
    color: #ff5555;
}
```